# lambda expression as a parameter

Tags: c#, lambda, parallel.foreach

I have a collection which I am looping using Parallel foreach. I would like to check each single item in the collection before I pass it on to the loop. I was trying to do something like this, but it gives an error.
Any thoughts or suggestions?

```
Parallel.ForEach(testCollection, (perform a check on each item in the collection) => DoSomething with the checked item)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "check each single item in the collection before I pass it on to the loop"?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you want to do? What exactly does "perform a check" mean?

Answer (score -1):

I understand you want to filter the data first (using Where)
http://www.dotnetperls.com/where